Intellij Gradle keeps building on its own
I am using Intellij version 2023.2.5 and using spring boot + gradle to run my project. Every time I try to reload the project when I make some changes in my code, the project keeps on building on its own. I know this is expected since intellij builds on its own whenever the code changes, but the problem is it keeps on building on top of already building processes. Sometimes the project can run up to 5 build processes at the same time. I have disabled all the related settings: Reload project after changes in the build scripts, Gradle auto build setting, etc. but to no avail

Could you please describe exact steps?
